# Не глупо ли звучит строчка из стихотворения: "Не вели переодеваться в страх"?

Tags: поэзия

«Переодеваться в страх» — звучит странно, поймёт ли читатель смысл, или же такое словосочетание будет абсурдным?

Comment: На первый взгляд, выглядит странно. Но нельзя судить, не увидев все стихотворение.

Comment: Лейся, дождь, хоть целый день –
Собран урожай.
Снова мысли набекрень.
Осень, наступай!
Превращай восторг в тоску
И наоборот.
По янтарному листку
Падай у ворот.
Понемногу заражай
Холодом и сном
Перегретый солнцем край.
Напои вином
Заблудившихся в мечтах,
Сломленных в пути.
Переодеваться в страх
Только не вели.
Пусть темнеет рано, пусть
Тучи в небесах,
И танцует ветер грусть
На моих плечах.
Проболеется душа.
Высохнет пальто.
В забытьё смахнёт слова
Время-помело.

Comment: Не думаю, что этому вопросу нужна правка. Вопрос не о мнениях, а об оценке художественного образа, о его понимании. А в более общем плане это вопрос о том, насколько свободен художник в создании  образов, есть ли какая-то грань, за которой кончается свобода и начинается небрежность и бессмысленность. Или художник может позволить себе любую вольность, а если читатель не понимает его, то тем хуже для него. Значит, это не его читатель или он попросту в поэзии не разбирается.

Comment: Переодеваться велят не в страх, а после испытанного страха

Answer (score 2):

Метафора ***переодеваться в страх*** притягивает внимание, кажется необычной и по первому впечатлению даже необоснованной, но потом понимаешь, **что она едва ли не основной  центр стихотворения**,  которое можно назвать "Осенние перемены".

Всё меняется осенью —  наша одежда и наши чувства. Светлая полоса, темная полоса, то восторг, то грусть и тоска.

Но здесь нужен край: **страх не должен входить в нашу душу.**

Answer (score 2):

Выражение "**переодеться с страх**" интересно своей нейтральностью по отношению к смыслу, который может зависеть от общего настроения лирического героя:

> Ты лейся себе дождь - хоть сутки напролёт.
>  Как собран урожай -
>   так мысли набекрень.
>  Янтарно-жёлтый лист ложится у ворот,
>   Восторг смешал с тоской осенний ясный день.
>
> Ты, осень, холодом и сном тихонько заряжай
>  Наш перегретый летним
>   солнцем край,
>  Да напои вином заблудшихся в мечтах, 
>  А
>   сломленных в пути ты привечай,
>  И **не вели переодеться в
>   страх**.
>
> Пусть тьма спешит настать под тучи в небесах,
>  Пусть ветру
>   танцевать "Грусть" на моих плечах -
>  Душа пройдёт сквозь хворь, и
>   высохнет пальто,
>  А время-помело слова смахнёт в слезах
>  В
>   забвения поток - не вспомнит их никто.

В других случаях можно придать этому выражению смысл, близкий к буквальному:

> **Переоденусь в страх** и бабою Ягою
>  Ступлю в твой сон я костяной
>   ногою.

Answer (score 1):

Дело вкуса. На мой взгляд, "переодевание в страх" — вполне приемлемый поэтический образ. А вот "проболеется душа" вызывает сомнения.

Comment: Оклемается душа – лучше?

Comment: Думаю, да. Оклематься, -аюсь, -аешься; совершенный вид (просторечное). То же, что выздороветь, прийти в себя (после болезни, недомогания).

Answer (score 1):

Лейся, дождь, хоть целый день —
Собран урожай.
Снова мысли набекрень.
Осень, наступай!
Превращай восторг в тоску
И **[—]** наоборот.
По янтарному листку **[листу]**
Падай у ворот.
Понемногу заражай
Холодом и сном
Перегретый солнцем край.
Напои вином
Заблудившихся в мечтах,
Сломленных в пути.
*Переодеваться в страх

Только не вели.*
Пусть темнеет рано, пусть
Тучи в небесах,
И танцует ветер грусть
На моих плечах.
Проболеется душа.
Высохнет пальто.
В забытьё смахнёт слова
Время-помело.

Да, конечно, у каждого — свое восприятие.
Я увидела такую ассоциативную цепочку: переодеваться в страх — облачаться в страх — покрываться (накрываться) страхом — испытывать страх от нахлынувших изменений (перемен) — не заставляй меня бояться (возможно — изменяться).
Такая логика для меня приемлема и нисколько не глупа.

P. S. В квадратных скобках — то, что я бы изменила.